# Print specific page of a paged node

Tags: paging

I am using [Print](https://drupal.org/project/print) module to print a Drupal node.
Recently users have asked the ability to print a node in form of individual pages.

For example if a paged 'Drupal' article spans on 5 pages, user wants the ability to print only 2nd page.

I tried to analyze the `var_dump` of a node (by pro-grammatically loading it) to find any information related to paging but I did not have any luck.

I am thinking to do paging of a node pro-grammatically and load different paged content in an array.

How can I do this ?

Please let me know if I need to provide more information.

Comment: How do you achieve a paged node?

Comment: I later discovered that system was using pagebreak to create different pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get specific paged content using following code.

```
  $data = node_load($nid);
  $pages = explode('<!--pagebreak-->' , $data->body['und'][0]['value']);
```